# How Jsx is valid javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I use react and jsx. my question is how jsx is a valid js syntax? only way that I think it's maybe true, is that react compiles all the file and converts jsx(s) to valid js. like what C preprocessor does with macros. is it true? and if it is true, is it right that we consider react as js library? I think it is higher level of a library.

if No, who it is done?

Comment: [Does this help](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-under-the-hood/)?

Comment: JSX is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JSX` is just syntactic sugar over function calls of `React.createElement`, It is transpiled by `Babel`.

As a developer you may not like the way how react elements are created, so React team gave the `JSX` syntax and It is very easy and you can co-relate with HTML.

No one is stopping you to use`React.createElement`. But that will your code overbloated.

Just take a case where you've decided to use Raw React then you would end up  as below.

```
const list =
  React.createElement('div', {},
    React.createElement('h1', {}, 'My favorite ice cream flavors'),
    React.createElement('ul', {},
      [
        React.createElement('li', { className: 'brown' }, 'Chocolate'),
        React.createElement('li', { className: 'white' }, 'Vanilla'),
        React.createElement('li', { className: 'yellow' }, 'Banana')
      ]
    )
  );
```

The above code will work as expected but It has some limitation:

1. Not readable
2. Not Maintainable

After using JSX syntax, you won't have these problems as you can see below using JSX.

```
<div>
  <h1>My favorite ice cream flavors</h1>
  <ul>
    <li className="brown">Chocolate</li>
    <li className="white">Vanilla</li>
    <li className="yellow">Banana</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see it on [`babeljs.io`](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIgHQHoDOMCeAbApmpAYzTQQG4AoC3AD0ljgBNcAzAQwFdt4WOA7QjGAQ-cAIJgwACgCUcAN4U4cKLhgcooqUuVwAPI2AA3AHw7d-gBYBGEwAlc2bBDgB3aIz0obZi8r2WAEwmAJIA5CBweGyawHwA5nAASrhsgl5BvrpehqY6MpQAvhRAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.16.4&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

If your component is

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello word</h1>
      <h2>I'm learning React</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

then It will be transpiled to

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = App;

require("./styles.css");

function App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello word"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h2", null, "I'm learning React"));
}
```

Comment: thank you. so in fact using jsx we do not write in javascript. so can we consider react as a framework? because it seems to be something above some simple APIs. it compiles our file and translates that. am I right?

Comment: @Redwan: React and JSX have been developed together but they are still independent. React does not rely on or need JSX.

Answer (score 4):

JSX is `not` a valid `JavaScript`.

JSX is a look-alike of JavaScript. A compiler [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) converts the JSX code into meaningful JavaScript code.
With a JSX compiler, you can transform JSX expressions to calls to [**React.createElement**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

**JSX:**

```
<p style={{color:'#000', background:'blue'}}>This is JSX</p>
```

**Compiled JavaScript:**

```
"use strict";

/*#__PURE__*/
React.createElement("p", {
  style: {
    color: '#000',
    background: 'blue'
  }
}, "This is JSX");
```

You can play along to see runtime compilation [here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwBwBAzgLgngNgUwLwG8UGMD2dMCcBcA5AMQAM5hANGAEYCG6A1gOa6YCuAdgCZE1zsEhAL7CAfABUAFgEsIYOWABSAZQAawAPQgxQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.16.4&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)